# Assembly MIPS printing integers and strings

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to print the integers 1-10 and inserting a blank line in between lines (Actually a string that says something), but my code isn't working properly. Am I on the right track?

```
    .text
    .align 2




main: 

lw $s0, 1
j loop

Exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    jr $ra 


loop:
    beq $v0, 11, Exit   

    li $v0, 1 #call for printing integer is 1
    syscall
    addi $a0, $a0, 1 #increment by 1

   move $s0,$a0

   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, out_string
   syscall
   move $a0,$s0


   j loop




    .data

out_string:     .asciiz "\n new line\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have somethimg to do with this line

```
move $a0,$s0
```

It's populating $a0 with unknown values

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you describe a problem to others, just saying that something *"isn't working properly"* isn't particularly helpful. That could mean pretty much anything.

There are multiple problems with your code. But if we begin with the infinite loop, it's not hard to see why that would happen:

The condition you have for exiting the loop is that `$v0 == 11`, but the value of `$v0` when you perform that check will always be either 4 or whatever value it had when your program started:

```
loop:
   beq $v0, 11, Exit   <-- On the first iteration $v0 will have some "random" value.
                           On subsequent iterations it will have the value 4 because
                           of the li $v0,4 below.
   ...
   li $v0, 4
   ...
   j loop
```

There are more than one way of fixing this. You could use a different register for the loop counter, or you could save the value of `$v0` on the stack and restore it later.

This isn't the only issue with your code though. For example, you're also using `$a0` for more than one thing within the loop.